# Custom path for Hashicorp Vault Kubernetes Auth Method does not work uisng CLI

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, vault

When I enable kubernetes auth method at default path (-path=kubernetes) it works. However, if it is enabled at custom path, the vault init and sidecar containers don't start.

kubernetes auth method enable at auth/prod

```
vault auth enable -path=prod/ kubernetes

vault write auth/prod/config \
    kubernetes_host="https://$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:443" \
    token_reviewer_jwt="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
    kubernetes_ca_cert=@/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt 


vault write auth/prod/role/internal-app \
    bound_service_account_names=internal-app \
    bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
    policies=internal-app \
    ttl=24h
```

What could be wrong with these auth configurations?

Comment: How are you deploying the `Vault`? Add the YAMLs, container logs/errors.

Comment: Vault init and sidecars are launched with default path. The issue is with custom path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you have deployed the vault but if your injector is true

```
injector:
  enabled: true
```

vault will be injecting the sidecars and init container. You should check the logs of **side car** or **init container** which is failing.

If you are using the K8s method to authenticate you should check out below annotation example and use them

```
annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-image: registry.gitlab.com/XXXXXXXXXXX/vault-image/vault:1.4.1
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-secrets: kv/secret-path-location
        vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: auth/<K8s-cluster-auth-name>
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: app
```

You can keep the multiple **auth-path** for different **K8s** clusters to authenticate with a single vault instance also.

If the vault is injecting the sidecar you should check the logs of it.

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/injecting-vault-secrets-into-kubernetes-pods-via-a-sidecar

Comment: May be  auth-path annotation is missing. let me try and confirm

Comment: check the logs of init conatiner and side car you will get idea from error.

Comment: Thank you!, its working now after adding the custom auth-path annotation vault.hashicorp.com/auth-path: "auth/prod"